# Javascript download function only downloading partial content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to download some content in a HTML file on button click and I found some code online that worked in initial tests, but when I implemented it on to my site I found that the downloaded file only included a small portion of the content I wanted downloaded.

Is there some kind of limit to the method I'm using, and if there is, what is the process for downloading something of a larger size?

See my current method below. I've omitted the on-click event because that's fine.

```js
let openingCode = $('.openingCode').text().trim()
let bodyCode = $('.emailContent').html().trim()
let closingCode = $('.closingCode').text().trim()
let contentToCopy = openingCode + bodyCode + closingCode
console.log(contentToCopy)

let downloadName = $('.fileNameText').val()
var a = document.body.appendChild(
  document.createElement("a")
);

a.download = downloadName + ".html";
a.href = "data:text/html," + contentToCopy;
a.click();
```

**Update**

I've changed my code to utilise a blob instead, following a suggestion below. I struggled to follow along with the example provided so tracked down some other examples of people using blobs to download html files, and made some changes to my code. However, my downloaded file is still ending at the same point in my content.

New code below

```
var a = document.body.appendChild(
       document.createElement("a")
   );
   var blob = new Blob([contentToCopy], {type: "text/html"});
   var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.href = url
a.download = downloadName + ".html";
a.click();
```

**Update 2**

My above update was a noob error! I was looking at my last deployed version, not my latest local version!

Using the blob has worked!

Comment: `data:` URIs do have a limit. Use [`Blob`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) instead.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Ok, but how to instruct the browser to download a Blob?

Comment: @FZs There’s an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Creating_a_URL_representing_the_contents_of_a_typed_array) on the documentation page I’ve linked to.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian and @FZs, I am reviewing this now. I may well have some followup questions!

Comment: Hi Sebastian and @FZs, I've updated my post above.